# set object property names

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

Maybe is a dummy question but I'd like to know the right way to achieve this:

i have an array of strings;
I 'd like to use it as properties for my stdclass object;
Why I cannot prepare it and then use it without give it a value on fly?

```
$heading= ["cgonboardingid","username","firstname","lastname","departement","lang","cgrole"];
$tmpUser =   new \stdClass();
```

this code won't work:

```
 foreach ($headings as $head){
                            $tmpUser->$head;
                        }
```

neither if i try to use `{$head}` or `{'$head'}`
This works!!!

```
 foreach ($headings as $head){
                            $tmpUser->$head='something';
                        }
```

Comment: `$tmpUser->$head;` would just mean _read_ access, and since none of those properties actually exist, it would give you a lot of `Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$cgonboardingid` as well. You want to perform an _assignment_ here, but that needs an actual _value_ to assign. You can replace the `'something'` with an empty string, false or null, if that helps any …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use null, false or '' instead of 'something'